# C# DataTable column type is not being properly set

Tags: c#, types, datatable

Having trouble with types in `DataTable`.  In the code below I have a data table and I specify types for each of the columns:

```
        logItems = new DataTable();
        logItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Machine_Name",typeof(string)));
        logItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Time_Stamp", typeof(DateTime)));
        logItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message_Text", typeof(string)));
        logItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message_Type",typeof(MsgType)));
```

Later when I try to use the data table it is as though the type of the table wasnt set.  For example here is me populating the table with some data.

```
            DataRow dataRow = logItems.NewRow();
            dataRow["Machine_Name"] = machineName;
            dataRow["Time_Stamp"] = GetDateTime(lineItem);
            dataRow["Message_Text"] = GetMsgText(lineItem);
            dataRow["Message_Type"] = GetMsgType(dataRow["Message_Text"]);
            logItems.Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

Signature for `GetMsgType` function is `MsgType GetMsgType(string messageText)`

I am having trouble with `dataRow["Message_Type"] = GetMsgType(dataRow["Message_Text"])` line: it doesnt work without the `ToString()` after it, and i am having trouble understanding why. The way I see it when i create new `DataRow` using `NewRow()` method it creates a data row of the same scheme as the `logItems`.  Therefore column `"Message_Text"` is of type `string` and therefore I should be able to use it as such when I use it in `GetMsgType` function, but its not working as expected since I get a "cannot convert from object to string" error.

Similarly I am having trouble doing a comparison on `"Message_Type"` column.  That column is declared as type `enum MsgType{}` (see above), and as far as I can tell, it is legal to use it as such:

```
        DataRow[] errorSubset = logItems.Select(query);
        foreach(DataRow lineACDC in errorSubset)
        {
            if (lineACDC["Message_Type"] == MsgType.Error) 
            {
```

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: What is MsgType?  Is it an enumeration?

Comment: Everything you access from datatable using datarow["column name"] is object. You need to cast it to target type when you retrieve it.

Comment: @jdweng:  yes,  MsgType is an enumeration.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you..  This is interesting:  then why is there a need to specify a type when you create data table, when upon retrieval it comes out as an object.

Comment: DataRow represents collection of items stored in columns. Now you can not have a collection which allows you to store different type of data and when you retrieve you get the same type back. There is no such collection in C#. If you want to store data with different datatypes in collection then the collection need to represent some base type and `object` is the base type of all the types in .NET. That's why datarow[columname] gives you data as object and you need to cast it to target type specifically.

Comment: An enumeration returns a number or the enumeration NAME when you specify ToString().  So if the database contains a string for the type then using ToString() makes perfect sense.